# How to create staging/dev/prod environments for AWS AppSync API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have an AWS AppSync API (maybe like 80% done) and I'd like to create environments for staging, development, production, etc. My initial googling led me to using Amplify to create environments but I didn't see anything about making environments for existing APIs. I've been using the console to develop the API (in case this detail is important). I'm new to using AWS so I'm not really sure what to look for but my question is how do I create different environments for my existing AppSync API?

Comment: Hi Donovan. This is not so straightforward.  Per my experience, your best bet is to setup an Amplify project, which allows you to use appsync/graphql schemas, as well as other AWS services, and migrate your schema there. But it takes learning Amplify and its' quirks. Easy to add environments via Amplify.

Comment: I figured I would have to use Amplify but was hoping for another (hopefully easier) way but at least I know the right path to go down. Thanks for the help gbones!